# Show <View> based on dynamic data in React-Nave?

Tags: react-native

I am new React-Native, I try to show some dynamic data inside View tag but I get an error: **text strings must be rendered within a  component**.

```
        {someValue &&
            <View>
                <Card>
                    <CardItem header>
                        <View>
                            <Text>Result :{someValue}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </CardItem>
                    <CardItem>
                        <Body>
                            <View>
                                <Text>
                                    {someInfo}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        </Body>
                    </CardItem>
                </Card>
            </View>
        }
```

Please help me to find out my mistake. Thanks:)

Comment: Is a basic example and I dont see any error, the text is render if you , if you delete `{someValue}` and `{someInfo}` parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here code looks `someInfo` value might bt empty or null, Try this way **( UPDATED )**

```
<CardItem header>
  {someValue && someValue.length > 0 ? (
    <View>
      <Text>Result :{someValue}</Text>
    </View>
  ) : null}
</CardItem>

<View>{someInfo && someInfo.length > 0 ? <Text>{someInfo}</Text> : null}</View>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still, I get the same error.

Comment: @Neotrixs I have updated my answer please try that